# How can I remove the last comma in my for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
function currentLine(katzDeliLine) {
    if (katzDeliLine.length > 0) {
        var textToPrint = "The line is currently: "

        for (var crrLine = 0; crrLine < katzDeliLine.length; crrLine++) {

            textToPrint = textToPrint + (crrLine + 1) + ". " + katzDeliLine[crrLine] + ","

        }


        return textToPrint;
    } else {
        return "The line is empty"
    }
}

var lineofpeople = ["katrina", "kevin", "vincent"]
```

Output is:
`The line is currently: 1. katrina, 2. kevin, 3. vincent,`

I'm trying to get rid of the last comma after 'vincent'

I tried an if statement, and I also tried the .join() method. I don't know how to implement them in the code.

Comment: Welcome, Kevin. Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

You could map the leading numbers with the value and join the array with comma.

```js
function currentLine(array) {
    return array.length
        ? `The line is currently: ${array.map((v, i) => `${i + 1}. ${v}`).join(', ')}.`
        : "The line is empty.";
}

var lineofpeople = ["katrina", "kevin", "vincent"];

console.log(currentLine(lineofpeople));
console.log(currentLine([]));
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is using **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** and **join()**.

Here you should pay attention that it's **not single quote** but a **backtick**.

```js
var lineofpeople = ["katrina", "kevin", "vincent"]
const emptyLine = []

// Using arrow function; the code is short
const currentLine = (line) => {
  return !line.length ? 'The line is empty' : `The line is currently: ${line.map((e, i) => `${i + 1}. ${e}`).join(', ')}`
}

console.log(currentLine(lineofpeople)) // expected: The line is currently: 1. katrina, 2. kevin, 3. vincent

console.log(currentLine(emptyLine)) // expected: "The line is empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last part of the returned string using `textToPrint.slice(0,-1)`

```
function currentLine(katzDeliLine) {
   if (katzDeliLine.length > 0) {
   var textToPrint = "The line is currently: "  

   for (var crrLine = 0;  crrLine < katzDeliLine.length; crrLine++) {
     textToPrint = textToPrint + (crrLine + 1)+". " +katzDeliLine[crrLine]+","
   }

   return textToPrint.slice(0,-1);
   } 
   else {
      return "The line is empty"
   }
}

 var lineofpeople = ["katrina", "kevin", "vincent"]
 console.log(currentLine(lineofpeople));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function currentLine(katzDeliLine) {
    if (katzDeliLine.length > 0) {
        var textToPrint = "The line is currently: "  

        for (var crrLine = 0;  crrLine < katzDeliLine.length; crrLine++) {

        textToPrint = textToPrint + (crrLine + 1)+". " 
        +katzDeliLine[crrLine]+","

}


return textToPrint.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
} else {
return "The line is empty"
}
}

var lineofpeople = ["katrina", "kevin", "vincent"]
console.log(currentLine(lineofpeople));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove the last comma

`$` is for matching the end of the string

```js
let line = 'string1, string2, string3, string4, string5,'

console.log(line.replace(/,$/g,''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the current index is the last one, if it is, don't add a comma:

```
for (var crrLine = 0; crrLine < katzDeliLine.length; crrLine++) {

        textToPrint = textToPrint + (crrLine + 1) + ". " + katzDeliLine[crrLine] + (crrLine != (katzDeliLine.length - 1) ? "," : "")

    }
```